# SQL insert if missing value

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been banging my head over this problem for the whole day. I'm posting here in hope that someone would be able to help me.

I'm trying to fix a database that has missing values, by adding them.

Let's say we have the following tables:

```
Color with columns (itemId, colorId)
Process with columns (itemId, colorId, iteration, rating)
```

Process contains entries only if the rating is bigger than 0. I want to fix that by adding the missing entries with rating == 0 for each iteration.

For instance, the table process contains:

```
item id | color id | iteration | rating
   1    |    1     |    1      |    1
   1    |    1     |    2      |    2
   1    |    1     |    3      |    2
   1    |    2     |    3      |    1
   1    |    1     |    4      |    5
   1    |    2     |    4      |    5
```

the missing entries are:

```
item id | color id | iteration | rating
   1    |    2     |    1      |    0
   1    |    2     |    2      |    0
```

I'm beginner in SQL and not very familiar with joins. I was thinking of using an insert select combine with a join. Maybe a cross join?

I would greatly appreciate your help! Thanks a lot!

PS: I'm using mysql, but I guess this wouldn't affect the answer.

EDIT: Thanks for your proposed solutions. However none of them works because it is assumed that the column iteration does not have missing values. However, for me it is the case. Please consider "iteration" as another id, not necessary incremental...

So what I really want is something that, whenever there is one entry in table process for a given itemId and iteration, then there is also one entry per colorId (matching itemId in table Color). The rating of this missing entry should be 0.

Comment: Do you have any Primary key or unique constraints ?

Comment: Do you have an upper limit for iteration in your current data?

Comment: @BeginnerJava I tried to simplify my problem to this toy problem. So I would say colorId is a primary key of Color, and for Process, there is no primary key (actually, there is an auto inc id, but it is not relevant I guess...)

Comment: @gwc there is no upper limit for iteration in the current data.

Comment: @laoheike - Why is it that `item_id=1, color_id=2, iteration=1, rating=0` is a missing entry, but `item_id=1, color_id=1, iteration=1, rating=0` (color_id **1** instead of **2**) is *not* a missing entry?

Comment: @EdGibbs The rating can be anything, but if it is 0 it's not in the process. What I mean is that for a given iteration and item id, I want one entry per color id. If there is one missing, then rating should be set to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
P.itemId
,C.colorId
,I.iteration
,0 AS rating
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT itemId FROM Process) P
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT colorId FROM Color) C
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT iteration FROM Process) I
LEFT JOIN
Process E
ON P.itemId = E.itemId
AND C.colorId = E.colorId
AND I.iteration = E.iteration

WHERE E.rating IS NULL
```

Comment: Assumes that the entire range of iterations exists in the process table. The whole problem is gaps in iterations. We don't know for certain that every iteration number exists. What if iteration 6 exists but iteration 5 was never entered.

Comment: if that is the case you can make a CTE (if that can be done in mySql) for the iterations. Edit: I see you already did something similar

Comment: Here the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66783/1) of this answer is correct for the given number-set in the question.

Answer (score 2):

`Updated` based on no missing iterations

```
INSERT INTO process (itemId, colorId, iteration, rating)
SELECT p1.itemId, p1.colorId, i.iteration, 0
  FROM (SELECT itemId, colorId, MAX(iteration) as max_iteration
          FROM process
         GROUP BY itemId, colorId
       ) p1
 INNER
  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT iteration FROM process) i
    ON i.iteration < p1.max_iteration
  LEFT OUTER
  JOIN process p2
    ON p2.itemId    = p1.itemId
   AND p2.colorId   = p1.colorId
   AND p2.iteration = i.iteration
 WHERE p2.iteration IS NULL;
```

Comment: I tried to [Fiddle this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66783/6) without the `INSERT` leaving the `SELECT` but got no results. Maybe i did something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO Process (item,color,iteration,rating)
SELECT C.item, C.color, I.iteration, 0 FROM Color C
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT iteration FROM Process) I
LEFT JOIN Process P
ON P.item=C.item AND P.color=C.color AND P.iteration=I.iteration
WHERE P.rating IS NULL
```

Comment: This statement works for the example given by the OP, and also for the case where there is another color with no ratings for any of the item's iterations.